# Linear Algebra: Diagonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a diagonalisable $n\times n$ matrix and $m(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\ldots(x-x_k)$ is a polynomial such that $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ are distinct eigenvalues of $A$.

1. Prove that $m(A)=o$.
2. If $q(x)$ is a polynomial such that $q(A)=O$, then show that $q(x)$ is divisible by $m(x)$.

For part $1$, I divided into $2$ cases such that $k=n$ and $k<n$. I know that $\det(A-xI)=p(x)$ where $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$. So, if I have $k=n$, then $p(x)=m(x)$. Plug in $x=A$, so I have shown that $m(A)=O$. For the case, $k<n$, I define a new polynomial such that $r(x)=(x-x_{k+1})\ldots(x-x_n)$, then $p(x)/r(x)=m(x)$. Now if we substitute $x=A$, then we get $m(A)=O$.

From part $2$, I tried to prove this by contradiction such that $q(x)$ is indivisible by $m(x)$, there will be a remainder $r(x)$, i.e. $q(x)=t(x)m(x)+r(x)$. But this method doesn't work well. Anyone has any suggestion for both parts $1$ and $2$?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Where you write in (1) "Plug in $\;x=A\;$ ..." is wrong. In fact, that's part of the standard wrong "proof" of Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. You could use this theorem for (1). The fact that $\;A\;$ is diagonalizable means its minimal polynomial is a product of *different* linear factors, and thus yout $\;m(x)\;$  **is** the minimal polynomial of  $\;A\;$ , and that gives you (2)

Comment: I would suggest proving (1) by showing $m(A)v = 0$, where $v$ is an eigenvector. Remember, if $x_i$ is the eigenvalue of $v$, then $(A - x_i I)v = 0$, and you can rearrange polynomial factors however way you like. Use the fact that diagonalisable operators have bases of eigenvectors. For (2), I would suggest showing $(x - x_i)$ is a factor of any such polynomial, computing $m(A)v$ where $v$ is an eigenvector for $x_i$, then using Factor Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for replying.